# winjs: how to navigate to html page using winjs libraries.?

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I was developing `windows store app` in the platform of `HTML5/JAVASCRIPT` and with installed template of `SPLIT APP`.

I want to display an `HTML` page. If i displayed using `HTML Hyperlink` attribute, the html page showed in full windows and i can't go back from that. The only way i have is need to reinitialize the app.

So, I went through all `winjs` libraries and its functions from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770584.aspx

From that link I used;

```
var hello = WinJS.UI.Pages.get('/def/f1.html');
```

If i used by explained in these libraries; f1.html is not shown in the app, instead below image is shown.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For single page navigation in windows store App for split App ,We may try with the following code snipet.
Here I have  added a page control in the Project and navigating to this  page from the app bar button click.so we need to add the button in the app bar in default.html

```
<div id="appbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar">
        <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmd', label:'Command', icon:'placeholder'}" type="button"></button>
           <button 
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" 
            data-win-options="{id:'cmdMove',label:'Remove',icon:'delete',
                section:'global',tooltip:'move item'}">
        </button>
    </div>
```

Then in the default.js

```
document.getElementById("cmdMove")
              .addEventListener("click", Move, false);

 function Move() {

        WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/test.html");

    }
```

It will navigate to test.html and when we will be at test.html ,it has a back button to get back to the previous page.